# The difference between type and newtype in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

From the book Programming in Haskell (http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/book.html), a parser is defined as follows:

```
> type Parser a = String -> [(a,String)]
```

However, from the sample code (http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/Parsing.lhs), the definition is a little bit different.

```
> newtype Parser a              =  P (String -> [(a,String)])
```

I found the difference from this page:https://wiki.haskell.org/Type#Type_and_newtype as follows:

> type introduces a synonym for a type and uses the same data constructors. newtype introduces a renaming of a type and requires you to provide new constructors.

Here are my questions:

1. For new type why `P(...)` is used to enclose the content?
2. It requires to provide new constructor with newtype, but I don't seem to find one from the example code. How to define constructor for newtype? Is it OK not to provide one?

Comment: `P` *is* the new constructor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> For new type why `P(...)` is used to enclose the content?

Any `newtype` declared type must have a single constructor.  In this case that constructor is named `P` and its type is

```
P :: (String -> [(a, String)]) -> Parser a
```

You can also use record syntax, so it would be equivalent to

```
newtype Parser a = P { runParser :: String -> [(a, String)] }
```

Or if you were to use a `data` type (in which case the wrapper does not get optimized away at runtime as easily), it would be very similar:

```
data Parser a = P { runParser :: String -> [(a, String)] }
```

> It requires to provide new constructor with newtype, but I don't seem to find one from the example code. How to define constructor for newtype? Is it OK not to provide one?

As mentioned above, the constructor to the `newtype Parser` is named `P`, and there must be exactly one constructor for a `newtype`.

Some more clarification, the `type` keyword constructs a simple alias.  For example, `String` is defined as

```
type String = [Char]
```

You can use `String` in any function that takes `[Char]`, and you can use `[Char]` in any function that takes `String`.  Since `FilePath` is defined as

```
type FilePath = String
```

Then you can use `FilePath` where ever you would use a `String` and thus anywhere you would use `[Char]`, and vice versa.  These are simply names for reducing more complicated types.  I would say that in practice it's more common to use `newtype` rather than `type` except in very simple cases, simply because it allows the type system to enforce things more in your software.  There are also disadvantages to `type`s, since you need language extensions to use them in `instance` declarations, and they must always be fully applied in other expressions.  The disadvantages of `newtype` is that you have to wrap/unwrap them a lot, but this can be more of a boon when working with truly complex programs.

Comment: Because it must be fully applied, it is also simply not possible to give the `type` version instances of higher-kinded classes such as `Monad`.