# When do we use newtype in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, newtype

I'm a bit confused with type and newtype. It is said that newtype can contain only one field. I also find a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815310/the-difference-between-type-and-newtype-in-haskell).

But still not quite clear.

> So if you want to declare different type class instances for a
>   particular type, or want to make a type abstract, you can wrap it in a
>   newtype and it'll be considered distinct to the type-checker, but
>   identical at runtime.

Any example would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Is there something in that other link that is still confusing? If you can expand on what you're not understanding, we might be able to provide more help. For me, I think of using newtypes to wrap anything I want to be specified. For example, instead of passing a bunch of `Text`s around and not knowing which `Text` is an email-y thing and which is a phone-number-y thing, I create two newtypes for `Email` and `Phone` that just wrap text values.

Comment: Here's my rule of thumb. I think beginners should follow it pretty strictly, and intermediate Haskellers should follow it unless there's a reason not to. 1. Don't use `type` at all; it's only useful in very special cases. 2. Use `newtype` whenever there's exactly one constructor and it has exactly one field. 3. Use `data` the rest of the time.

Comment: FYI, the main cases where I think `type` is a reasonable thing: 1. Higher-rank type synonyms: `type f ~> g = forall x. f x -> g x`, `type Lens s t a b = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t` 2. Type synonyms that expand to constraints, for use in the "wrapper class" pattern: `type FooS a b c = (...,...,...,...); class FooS a b c => Foo a b c; instance FooS a b c => Foo a b c`. 3. Type synonyms that expand to type family applications: `type Reverse xs = RO '[] xs; type family RO acc xs where {RO acc '[] = acc; RO acc (x ': xs) = RO (x ': acc) xs}`

Comment: Please see: https://wiki.haskell.org/Type

Comment: If you sort a `[Int]` you get the standard increasing order. If you want to use your own order, one option (even if not the only one) is to `newtype MyInt = MyInt Int` and then `instance Ord MyInt where ...` to define a custom order. After that, if you sort `[MyInt]` you'll get the elements sorted by the custom order. Newtypes are often used so that one can "change" (roughly speaking) some predefined class instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example usage collected from the quote you posted would perhaps be declaring two `Int` monoids. There are multiple ways to consider `Int` a monoid (multiplication or addition), and perhaps you wish to use more than one. You can not define more than one monoid instance for `Int`, but you can instead create two newtypes and provide separate instances for them.

```
newtype SumInt = SumInt Int 
newtype ProdInt = ProdInt Int 

instance Monoid SumInt where
  mempty = SumInt 0
  (SumInt a) `mappend` (SumInt b) = SumInt (a + b)

instance Monoid ProdInt where
  mempty = ProdInt 1
  (ProdInt a) `mappend` (ProdInt b) = ProdInt (a*b)
```

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning as a curiosity (and to help better understand the issue) that Idris does that using 'named implementations' (which Haskell doesn't have) http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/interfaces.html#named-implementations