# couldn't match expected type (newtype)

Tags: haskell, newtype

I'm working on a function

```
createTypeBoard :: (Int, Int) -> CellType -> Board
```

using these types

```
newtype Board = Board [(Cell, CellType)] deriving(Eq)

data CellType  = Mine                
           | Flag                    
           | Void                     
           | Enumerated Int          
           | Undiscovered             
           deriving Eq

type Cell = (Int, Int)
```

createTypeBoard (2,2) Mine should be: Board [((1,1), X), ((1,2), X), ((2,1), X), ((2,2), X)]

(X is the show instance of Mine)

my idea was to use zip:

```
createTypeBoars (a, b) c = zip (createCells (a, b)) [c]
```

but I keep getting an error

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Board’
              with actual type ‘[(Cell, CellType)]’
• In the expression: zip (createCells (a, b)) [Flag]
  In an equation for ‘createTypeBoard’:
      createTypeBoard (a, b) Flag = zip (createCells (a, b)) [Flag]
```

Board basically is [(Cell, CellType)] so I don't really get what the problem is :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared `Board` with `newtype`, but you're trying to use it as if you declared it with `type`. Two choices to fix it:

1. Declare `board` like this instead: `type Board = [(Cell, CellType)]`
2. Use the `Board` data constructor in `createTypeBoard`, like this: `createTypeBoard (a, b) c = Board $ zip (createCells (a, b)) [c]`

For more information on the difference between `type` and `newtype`, which may affect your decision on which fix to go with, see [Haskell type vs. newtype with respect to type safety](https://stackoverflow.com/q/991467/7509065) and/or [The difference between type and newtype in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31815310/7509065).