# Why is (&) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b not treated as Monad?

Tags: haskell, monads

Mathematically, the binary operation for function application is an endo-Functor/Monad.

```
pipe :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
pipe = \f -> \a -> f a

(|>) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
(|>) = flip pipe

infixl 1 |>
```

It's called pipeline-operator, and in Haskell, predefined as

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-38-

`(&) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b`

```
monadTestPipe :: IO ()
monadTestPipe = do
  "Monad Laws========" & print
  let i = id

  let a = (3 :: Int)
  let f = (\a -> a + 1) >>> i
  let g = (\a -> a * 2) >>> i
  let m = f a -- 4
  "---------------------------------" & print
  do
    "-- Left/Center/Right identity" & print
    let lft = a & i & f
    let ctr = a & f -- = m
    let rit = a & f & i
    ---------------------------------
    lft & print -- 4
    ctr & print -- 4
    rit & print -- 4
    "---------------------------------" & print
  do
    "-- Associativity" & print
    -- m = f a -- 4
    (m & f) & g
      & print -- 10 = (4+1)x2
    m & (\x -> f x & g)
      & print -- 10
    "---------------------------------" & print
```

Why is the pipeline-operation `(&) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b` not treated (at least not integrated) as Monad in Haskell?

Or, it's probably fine to say, I've never read that in any Haskell wiki or books.

Edit: I want to make my question as concise as possible in order to prevent diffusion of issues, but

```
class Applicative m => Monad m where
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
  return :: a -> m a
```

`>>=` is simply a symbol of Monad type class in Haskell, and `&` can be integrated to `>>=` because `&` is a monad operator in mathematical sense.

`return` is `id :: a -> a`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242316/discussion-on-question-by-sailsky-why-is-a-a-b-b-not-treated-a).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is treated as the bind operation (aka `(>>=)`) of a monad (specifically the identity monad), just not directly. You must use a wrapper, due to the way the type system works: you cannot have a type synonym like `type Id a = a` as an instance of `Monad` and there are no type-level lambdas.

`type Id a = a` simply describes a synonym: `a` and `Id a` are the same type.

You cannot have an instance like

```
instance Monad Id
```

using the above definition of `Id` because `Id` is in essence the same as a type-level lambda `\a -> a` (if such a thing existed in Haskell), and [Haskell doesn't have this kind of type-level lambda, since they would make Haskell's type system undecidable](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177967/why-doesnt-haskell-have-type-level-lambda-abstractions).

However, this is exactly one of the main reasons the `newtype` construct was created. It creates a new type (as its name suggests) which wraps the old type and only exists to distinguish between the old type and the new one at a type-level. They even have the same runtime representation. You can read more about the difference between the two [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815310/the-difference-between-type-and-newtype-in-haskell).

In this case, the wrapper is called [`Identity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html).

Comment: Well, thanks and I should have mentioned all of what I already knew in the Question for the `Identity` monad. For type system limitation, if that is the major reason. I think the fact should be more announced.